# Can't run "python manage.py runserver" via command prompt

Tags: python, django, python-3.6, python-packaging

I want to run "python manage.py runserver", when doing so I get the error which says "Watchman unavailable: pywatchman not installed..". When installing pywatchman by typing pip install pywatchman I get error written " Failed building wheel for pywatchman"

Please anybody with solution

Comment: which os are you using

Comment: if you are using a virtual environment, you may need to activate it.

Comment: You need to run `pip install wheel` first, then run `pip install pywatchman`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider using a seperate environment for your project. This way all dependencies are matched.

Here is a [description](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) how to use environments with `conda`.

The good thing about this approach is that you can change the version of your software (e.g. python) at any time, not affecting your other projects.

Moreover you can use `pip` in it just as before.